# calculate average of values in column based on target values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this sample of a data frame. I would like to find an average value for each assignment type value according to the target value. For example, for rows with pass result, I want to calculate their average C and T. There are about 5 Cs, and 3 Ts based on time. id_assigment differentiate between them you can see, but I want to find the average for each C and T for each class value. For example, average C with id 45 for Pass rows, for Fail rows,etc.  I wonder how to calculate the averages?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try [pd.pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)

```
pd.pivot_table(df, columns=['id_assignemnt', 'assignemnt_type', 'result'], values='score')
```